# SwiftUI + Core Data crash when using `.allObjects` of a "To Many" relationship entry

Tags: core-data, swiftui

I am constantly getting crash reports with a stack trace like this:

```
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x0000000199e6a334 object_getMethodImplementation + 48 (objc-object.h:97)
1   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001853d35a4 _NSIsNSSet + 40 (NSObject.m:381)
2   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001852a6888 -[NSMutableSet unionSet:] + 108 (NSSet_Internal.h:56)
3   CoreData                        0x000000018b4af3b0 -[_NSFaultingMutableSet willReadWithContents:] + 636 (_NSFaultingMutableSet.m:167)
4   CoreData                        0x000000018b53c3a0 -[_NSFaultingMutableSet allObjects] + 32 (_NSFaultingMutableSet.m:340)
```

My code is doing the following, this is inside the Core Data auto generated class (I am using the code bellow inside an extension I have made to that class):

```
if let tasks = tasks?.allObjects as? [Task] {
}
```

where `tasks` are `@NSManaged public var tasks: NSSet?`, this is the "array" object from core data (the auto generated one).

Any ideas what is wrong here, maybe it is a Core Data issue itself, SwiftUI + Core Data for some reason.

Comment: Could you add some more context, for instance why is `tasks` a variable instead of accessing it directly from the to-one object?

Comment: Ofc, the `tasks` is the property of the Core Data generated entry class. I have made extension to that class which is how I can use the `tasks` directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the latest SwiftUI 3 I have stopped seeing this crash.

Initially this is exactly what I was thinking the source of the problem is (internal SwiftUI issue) and it is proving to be just that.

Answer (score 0):

This is the way I do it, as a computed property in the class extension, and never had issues.

```
var allTasks: [Task] {
tasks?.allObjects as? [Task] ?? [ ]
}
```

you could add the if let inside and do any sorting or filtering and return that.

Comment: Thank you I will try and see if this works for my case, lets hope it does a I am still getting those errors from time to time. Most often when the app has been in the background for couple of hours.